# Magnetic field at infinity

Tags: magnetic-fields

Does a magnetic field, generated by permanent magnets (for instance), vanishes "theoretically" (according to Maxwell's equations) at a very long (infinite) distance from the magnetizing devise?

What about the "real" case?

Is there an explanation that proves or disapproves this?

Thank you.

Comment: Every reciprocal function converges to zero at infinity. $$\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \frac{c}{x} = 0$$

Answer (score 3):

If you for example look at the [Biot-Savart law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law#Electric_currents_.28along_closed_curve.29), you'll see that the magnetic field decreases with the square of the distance when you move away from the current that generates the field. The same goes for a static magnet: you can in general expect that $\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}) \sim 1/\|\mathbf{r}\|^2$ in the magnetostatic case, which means that $\mathbf{B}\rightarrow 0$ as $\| \mathbf{r}\| \rightarrow \infty$. (In the case of a magnetic dipole of limited size, you get the [even nicer behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole) $\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}) \sim 1/\|\mathbf{r}\|^3$, which drops to zero even faster as $\|\mathbf{r}\| \rightarrow \infty$.)

Comment: Does this still true if the magnetic flux is driven by a ferromagnetic tube, for example, of infinite length?

Answer (score 2):

A magnetic fiels behaves pretty much as an electric field. Actually you can transform one into another just by changing your inertial frame of reference to a moving one. The imposrant different for this example is that isolated magnetic charges (magnetic monopoles), do no seem to exist, so the magnetic field of a magnet will take a similar shape than that of an  electric fiel dipole (a system consisting of two separated charges of opposite sign).  Thus, the magnetix field, in the same way as an electric dipole field, will vanish at infinity.